# image not loading on web browser

Tags: reactjs, image-loading

I am getting the following error while running react app:

Failed to compile.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ' ../asset/intro.jpg' in 'C:\my-app\src\components'
ERROR in ./src/components/HeroImg.js 7:0-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ' ../asset/intro.jpg' in 'C:\my-app\src\components'

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

## HeroImg.js

```
import "./HeroStyles.css";
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import IntroImg from " ../asset/intro.jpg";

const HeroImg = () => {
  return (
      <div className="hero" >
       <div className="mask">
        <img className="into-img" src={IntroImg} alt="introimage"/>
       </div>

       <div className="content">
         <p>HI, I'M A FREELANCER.</p>
         <h1>React Developer</h1>
         <div>
          <Link to="/project" className="btn">Projects</Link>
          <Link to="/contact" className="btn btn-light">Contact</Link>

         </div>

      
      
       </div>
      </div>
  );
};
export default HeroImg
```

ollowing is the folder hierarchy:
-src

-asset

```
   -intro.jpg
```

I am new to react and following a tutorial. I have write as it is as the code in the tutorial and I have also checked it so many times..
I have check the path, it is written correctly, I tried to configure this error using require statement but not working for me....

Anyone can help me out configuring this error....

Comment: It the title the correct one for the body (I see no web-browser in the body).

Comment: The 3rd from last paragraph is a mess. Please edit and address problems.

Comment: Thanks ctrl-alt-delor,
  It's the formatting mistake only :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a stray space in the file name.

Answer (score 0):

`import Intro Img from "../asset/intro.jpg";`

Comment: I have added these lines in my code but still giving errors.